# Detect if we gets new response from API

Tags: ajax, reactjs, api

I am working on a React app.

I want to refresh my component details every time when it gets a new response from the API.
Can anyone please tell me, how can I detect if we get new response from API so that I could refresh my details.
Thank you !

Comment: You mean you want your component to have kind of "event listener" for arriving data form the server?

Comment: ya right. I am trying to use react-websocket. But i am facing some issues there also. If you have other options please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried following [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34) tut?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stateful component and set the state to the data received from API. As reactJS uses Virtual DOM to check the changes made to the state, it will automatically get updated if there are any changes to the data received from your API request.

You can try something similar to this :

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      flats : []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const url="example.com/api.json";
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        flats: data
      });
    })
  }
```